# Share model and libraries from rails app to sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have create app.rb file under lib directory in my rails project. The goal of this approach is to create reset web service API for my rails project. Hence, I thought to share all the models and libraries in sinatra app. PFB my code.

```
RAILS_ROOT = '../..'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/all'
require 'active_support/dependencies'

relative_load_paths = %w(app/models lib)
::ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths = relative_load_paths.map { |path|
  File.expand_path(path, RAILS_ROOT)
}

require 'active_record'
::ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    YAML.load(File.read(
    File.expand_path('config/database.yml', "..")))["development"])

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Base

  get '/:id' do
    purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
    {"pcategory" => purchase.category.name}.to_json
  end

end

App.run!
```

I ran the commands in terminal

```
> ruby app.rb
> curl localhost:4567/12321
```

But I got the following error message. Can anyone help me in this? thx.

```
NameError - uninitialized constant App::Purchase:
   web_service/app.rb:56:in `block in <class:App>'
```

**Updated:**

I have included all my models in the line 6. Purchase is a model class. I have list of models under the directory app/models.

Comment: Your Sinatra Class 'App' can't know about the Rails App because you're not inheriting / including / extending it in any way. Is 'Purchase' a module or a class? Please add more information of 'Purchase' what is it, how is it nested.

Comment: I'd drop the autoloading and just use `require` or `require_relative`.